# Type-safe `a` tag helper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, strong-typing

One of the most popular books on ASP.NET Core is *Pro ASP.NET Core 3* by Adam Freeman.

In chapters 7-11, he builds an example application, SportsStore:

[image]

On the left, you'll notice the buttons for various product categories ("Chess", "Soccer", etc.). These links are generated by the following code:

```
@foreach (string category in Model) {
    <a class="btn btn-block
       @(category == ViewBag.SelectedCategory 
           ? "btn-primary": "btn-outline-secondary")"
       asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home"
       asp-route-category="@category"
       asp-route-productPage="1">
        @category
    </a>
}
```

[Views/Shared/Components/NavigationMenu/Default.cshtml](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-3/blob/master/09%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Cart/End%20of%20Chapter/SportsSln/SportsStore/Views/Shared/Components/NavigationMenu/Default.cshtml)

## Type-safe reference to action

This part:

```
asp-action="Index"
```

refers to the `Index` method in `HomeController`. However, this bit of code is not type-safe; if we have a typo:

```
asp-action="IndexAbc"
```

the project still compiles.

OK, no worries, we can fix that:

```
asp-action="@nameof(HomeController.Index)"
```

There we go. Now a typo such as the following will give us an immediate error at edit time and the project will of course not compile:

```
asp-action="@nameof(HomeController.IndexAbc)"
```

## Type-safe reference to controller

The reference to the controller is also not type-safe:

```
asp-controller="Home"
```

Solving this one is more verbose, but is doable:

```
asp-controller="@Regex.Replace(nameof(HomeController), "Controller$", String.Empty)"
```

Again, now typos in the controller name are caught at compile time. If the controller is renamed, this will also catch that as well.

## Type-safe route parameters

How about also working with route values in a type-safe manner? Here are the two parameters and values we're dealing with:

```
asp-route-category="@category"
asp-route-productPage="1"
```

We can't really use `nameof` as in the previous cases; there's nothing to really use `nameof` on.

Here's the [`Index`](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-3/blob/master/09%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Cart/End%20of%20Chapter/SportsSln/SportsStore/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L15) method signature:

```
public ViewResult Index(string category, int productPage = 1)
```

It's almost like we'd like to be able to say `nameof(productPage)` but we don't have access to the `productPage` parameter in our view component.

Let's take a step back...

The following code:

```
<a class="btn btn-block @(category == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? "btn-primary" : "btn-outline-secondary")"
   asp-action="Index"
   asp-controller="Home"
   asp-route-category="@category"
   asp-route-productPage="1">
    @category
</a>
```

ultimately gets expanded into something like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary" href="/Chess/Page1">
    Chess
</a>
```

In particular, these lines:

```
asp-action="Index"
asp-controller="Home"
asp-route-category="@category"
asp-route-productPage="1"
```

get squashed down to just something like this:

```
href="/Chess/Page1"
```

ASP.NET Core allows us to perform this mapping [programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#url-generation-reference) using the method `LinkGenerator.GetPathByAction`.

So for example, the following call:

```
_linkGenerator.GetPathByAction("Index", "Home", new { category = "Chess", productPage = 1 })
```

gives us the following:

```
"/Chess/Page1"
```

We're very close now. The challenge now is that the following:

```
new { category = "Chess", productPage = 1 }
```

is not type-safe. The following typos do not prevent the project from building:

```
new { categoryAbc = "Chess", productPageXyz = 1 }
```

Let's change the `Index` method to receive an object as a parameter:

```
public ViewResult Index(IndexParameters parameters)
```

where `IndexParameters` is:

```
public class IndexParameters
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int ProductPage { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

Now we can pass the parameter values in a type-safe manner:

```
_linkGenerator.GetPathByAction("Index", "Home", new IndexParameters() { Category = category, ProductPage = 1 }))
```

## Full type-safe example

OK so now we have arrived at the full type-safe `a` tag:

```
<a class="btn btn-block @(category == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? "btn-primary" : "btn-outline-secondary")"
   href="@(
    _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction(
        nameof(HomeController.Index), 
        Regex.Replace(nameof(HomeController), "Controller$", String.Empty),
        new IndexParameters() 
        { 
            Category = category, 
            ProductPage = 1 
        }))">
    @category
</a>
```

I have added the following items to the view component file for this new version of the code:

```
@using SportsStore.Controllers
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions 
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing

@inject LinkGenerator _linkGenerator
```

My question is... is there a more concise way to get the same level of type-safety in the same code? Or do I really have to jump through all those hoops to make the code type-safe?

Comment: If type-safe is important to you, I can only think of a way, and that is to create links completely on the server, in Controller, and pass them to the view via view models.

Comment: I updated the full example at the end so that it's multi-line instead of all on one line. That makes it look a little better.

Comment: @DavidLiang As far as I know, with the approach above, the code is run completely on the server, although not totally in the controller; some of it is done in the view component.

Comment: Yea I got that. I guess what I meant was that, instead of use tag helpers on the view to generate links with parameters, you generate the links in the controllers and pass them back to the views as string...

Comment: @DavidLiang Someone suggested that I look into the R4MVC project. I've added an answer with a reference to that project. It does sound promising!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user [quentech](https://www.reddit.com/user/quentech) on reddit [who suggested](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/hv7riv/aspnet_core_typesafe_link_code/) the following project:

> [R4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/R4MVC) is a Roslyn based code generator for ASP.NET MVC Core apps that creates strongly typed helpers that eliminate the use of literal strings in many places.

It appears that this project aims to solve some of the same issues I've demonstrated in the question.

Video demonstrating statically typed tag helpers provided by R4MVC:

https://youtu.be/cFD9QOjEIxc

Answer (score 1):

2 main approaches to accomplish this:

- code generation - generate helper classes based on reflecting upon your controllers, models, etc.
- the more modern approach would be to write a Roslyn code analyzer that would issue a warning (or an error) if you reference non-existing action.

something to think about: you can even go further, for example ensuring you pass correct parameters to links and so on...

Comment: Thank you Zdravko! Yes, someone just recommended that I take a look at the [R4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/R4MVC) project which appears to take the approach that you recommend here. I've also added an answer referencing that project.

Comment: Here's a video demonstrating type-safe tag helpers provided by R4MVC: [link](https://youtu.be/cFD9QOjEIxc).